# Mockk: cannot specify an answer for method call

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, mockk

I have the following method call in my Kotlin class:

```
myService.trigger(id, processVariables, transientVariables)
```

... where "id" is a String, "processVariables" is a Java Map<String, Object> and "transientVariables" is a Kotlin MutableMap<String, Any>.

How to I specify the answer to return in a unit test for this circumstance? I have tried the following:

```
every { myService?.trigger(MY_ID, any(), any()) } returns unit
```

... but I get an error when the unit test runs:

```
io.mockk.MockKException: no answer found for: MyService(#2).trigger(MY_ID, {}, {key=value})
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: I've also tried "every { myService?.trigger(allAny()) } returns unit", but get the same error.

Comment: Why do you have a safe call here. Could you please try this myService.trigger(any(), any(), any())?

Comment: It won't let me: Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type MyService?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround that can be compiled and results in a successful test run is to populate the Map with values:

```
val map = mapOf("Key" to "Value")
every { processInstance.processVariables } returns map

every { myService?.trigger(EXECUTION_ID, map, any()) } returns unit
```